# masm32 ввод числа с клавиатуры

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

Добрый день!

Не могу найти хороший способ ввода с клавиатуры. Пока остановился на `ReadConsoleA` + `atodw`. Но вот только число получается умноженным на 100 + 2428.

Код:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
_data segment
_data ends
_text segment

option casemap:none

ExitProcess proto :dword

GetStdHandle proto :dword

ReadConsoleA proto :dword,:dword,\
  :dword,:dword,:dword

includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data

  stdin DWORD ?
  stdout DWORD ? 
  cWritten DWORD ?
  buff byte 16 dup (0)
  cRead DWORD ?
  sss dd 0
  ddd dd 0
  ifmt db "%d", 0
  .code

start:

  invoke GetStdHandle, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
  mov stdin, EAX
  invoke GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
  mov stdout, EAX

  invoke ReadConsoleA, stdin, ADDR buff, sizeof buff, ADDR cRead, 0
  ;теперь buff содержит введенную строку
  invoke atodw, offset buff
  ;почему-то после выполнения atodw число получается умноженым на 100 + 2428
  ;поправляем
  mov sss, EAX
  add sss, -2428  ;отнимаем 2428
  mov EAX, sss
  mov ddd, 100
  div ddd         ;делим на 100
  mov sss, EAX

  invoke wsprintf, ADDR buff, ADDR ifmt, sss ;форматируем число для вывода
  invoke WriteConsoleA, stdout, ADDR buff,\
    sizeof buff, ADDR cWritten, 0            ;выводим число   

  invoke ExitProcess, 0  ;завершаем процесс

end start
```

Подскажите, почему так получается. И какие ещё есть способы ввода числа с клавиатуры?

Comment: Сейчас нет возможности проверить, почему `atodw` неправильно может работать. Насколько я понял, это специфичная для masm32 функция, ни в одной стандартной dll ее нет, а под рукой только fasm. Вечером может посмотрю. Как вариант можно вместо нее можно использовать `sscanf` из `msvcrt.dll`.

Comment: sscanf попробую, спасибо!

Comment: Увидеть бы atodw, которая скорее всего в masm32rt.inc. под руками нет ... Немного вне темы: а вы нарочно все вычисления производите в памяти, что бы программа работала как можно дольше ? (можно же было просто `sub eax, 2428; mov ebx, 100; div ebx` регистры для того и сделаны что в них операции в разы быстрее чем с внешней памятью ...

Comment: @Mike это моя ~третья программа:) ещё не привык, полуслучайно стал преподавать ассемблер в школе, приходится и самому изучать. Спасибо, да, переменные лишние тут. atodw действительно в masm32rt.inc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего `ReadConsoleA` кладет в буфер перевод каретки принятый в windows, т.е. два байта 0x0D и 0x0A. А функция atodw из masm32 sdk при переводе числа из ascii представления в двоичное не проверяет, что в буфере находятся именно цифры, а выполняет для каждого байта входной строки стандартную операцию для перевода ascii цифры в двоичное представление, т.е. вычитает 0x30 из байта (с игнорированием переполнения).

```
0x0D-0x30 = 0xDD
0x0A-0x30 = 0xDA
0xDD * 10 + 0xDA = 0x97C = 2428
```

Вот и получили ваше загадочное число 2428 ...

Рекомендую после ввода данных проверять их на то, что они цифры, завершая строку как только встречена первая не цифра (как делают многия языки программирования при попытке конвертации строки в число) и только после этого использовать atodw на строке, очищенной от всего лишнего.

т.е. что то в этом роде (проверять не на чем, код не проверен):

```
     mov esi, offset buff
nxt:
     mov al, [esi]
     inc esi
     cmp al, 30h
     jb  done
     cmp al, 3Ah
     jb  nxt
done:
     dec esi
     xor al, al
     mov [esi], al
```

Возможно в masm32 для этого есть готовые функции, но это мне не известно.

Comment: Да, похоже на правду. Спасибо!

Comment: @pegoopik И кстати, учитывая, что собственно перевод в двоичку состоит из такого же цикла и еще 3 инструкций можно было бы просто вписать их сюда же и вот уже готовый свой atodw :) Кстати гляньте исходники в m32lib/atodw.asm меня так порадовало их умножение на 10 одновременно с сложением, двумя lea ... :)